# ffmpeg scale filter takes too long

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, android-blur-effect

I am using below command to scale and blur a video but it is very slow. Can anyone please help if i can improve the speed somehow.

```
"ffmpeg -i $inputPath -lavfi [0:v]split=2[original][copy];[copy]scale=ih*16/9:-1,crop=h=iw*9/16,boxblur=luma_radius=50:chroma_radius=25:luma_power=2[blurred];[blurred][original]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2[final] -map [final] -map a:0 -g 2 -preset ultrafast $outputPath -y"
```

Answer (score 1):

[avgblur](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#avgblur) or [gblur](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#gblur) filters may be slightly faster, and stream copy the audio (`-c:a copy`) instead of re-encoding it.

Comment: i tried both avgblur and gblur but both of them give the same speed = 0.1x -0.2x.

Comment: @Prashant_Sarin How fast is it without any blur filter?

Comment: actually i found the issue. Its scaling that takes time. Can you please help with that?  i removed scaling part from above code and the speed was increase to 0.5x as compared to 0.1x previously.

Comment: @Prashant_Sarin Show your new command and the complete log from the command. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62342713/edit) your question to add this info.

Comment: its the same command till now but i have to optimize scaling filter now.

Comment: @Prashant_Sarin The log will be needed if you want more suggestions.